# Which scripture is the source of the following sloka?

Tags: identification-request, other-religions, shloka, jainism

Sri Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath quotes one line of a sloka in one of His writings:

> na sikshed yaavanim bhaashaam na gachched jaina-mandiram

meaning : One should not learn any European (Yaavani) language and go to any Jain temple.

Which scripture is the source of this sloka? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing I found is in **Bhavishya Purana 3.28.53**  which says following:

> 53. na vadet yāvanīṁ bhāṣāṁ prāṇaiḥ kaṇṭhagatair api ||
>       gajair āpīdyamāno ’pi na gacchej jainamandiram ||
>
> One should not speak the Yāvanī language, even when his/her life is in his/her throat. (Also,) one should 
>   not go to a Jaina temple, even when pressed by elephants.